# C# chunk streams to http repsonse

Tags: c#

I am adopting the code from here

```
https://forums.asp.net/t/1556522.aspx?RDLC+Export+directly+to+Excel+or+PDF+from+codebehind
```

I construct my byte array

```
byte[] bytes = viewer.LocalReport.Render("PDF", null, out mimeType, 
                                    out encoding, 
                                    out extension, out streamIds, out warnings);

Response.Buffer = true;
Response.Clear();
Response.ContentType = mimeType;
Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", "attachment; filename=" + fileName + "." + extension);
Response.BinaryWrite(bytes); // create the file
Response.Flush(); // send it to the client to download
```

However i am worried about the bytes being huge around 4Gb and writing it to http response needs to be streamed in chunks.

I am on .net version 4.6 any idea how i can write the stream in chunks to the response object ?
When Response.BinaryWrite(bytes) will die if the bytes is huge and i am planning to replace that but wondering how ?

My research took me to 
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms252172.aspx

Where the render method can render to a stream object

```
public void Render(
    string format,
    string deviceInfo,
    CreateStreamCallback createStream,
    out Warning[] warnings
)
```

How do I chunk the data from the stream callback to an HTTP response object any clues ?

Comment: A PDF being over 4GB is going to be a real problem for anyone viewing it ;)

You would need to loop through the file reading chunks in and doing BinaryWrite on each chunk.

Answer (score 0):

Return a `FileResult` and define `octet-stream` as the MIME type:

```
public FileResult Download()
{
    byte[] fileBytes = System.IO.File.ReadAllBytes(@"c:\folder\myfile.ext");
    string fileName = "myfile.ext";
    return File(fileBytes, System.Net.Mime.MediaTypeNames.Application.Octet, fileName);
}
```

It will stream and the browser will figure out the file type based on the file name.

Comment: This will likely have the same negative side effect of the original code: it will hold up the connection and can't be resumed.

Comment: I may have misunderstood, but he didn't say anything about it taking a long time, he just wanted a way to stream in chunks. Which is what this code will do. But if he's worried about it taking too long and timing out and not being able to be resumed, then he needs something far more involved than a single stream.

Comment: This may also have another big problem the original proposal has, the byte array might overflow if the file is over 4GB.

Comment: If he's dealing with single files over 4gb he needs to be using a FileStream for the result instead reading it all into a single byte array anyways.